# How to display buildnumber in spring-based web application

Tags: spring, jsp, maven-2, build-process

I need to display build number in my index.jsp page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Title (build: BUILDNUMBER )
</head>
```

The build number can be supplied by maven into a *.properties file.
What is the best way to read *.properties file and display a property with Spring?

Comment: Do you want a Spring based solution or a Maven based solution (e.g. filtering the JSP)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may load the `.properties` file as a localization message source (using [`ResourceBundlerMessageSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource)) and access it in JSP using `<spring:message>` or `<fmt:message>`:

`src/main/resources/buildInfo.properties`:

```
buildNumber=${buildNumber}
```

where `buildNumber` is exposed as Roland Schneider suggests.

Context configuration:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name = "basenames"><value>buildInfo</value></property>
    <!-- Or a comma separated list if you have multiple .properties files -->
</bean>
```

JSP file:

```
Version: <spring:message code = "buildNumber" />
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: The bird have flew after i've added liteners to web.xml:

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

Comment: They key part that was missing in other answers/tutorials I found was the `<resources>` section of `pom.xml`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I've done it, using maven + jstl and leaving out Spring as it just makes it more complicated.

build.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="dateValue" class="java.util.Date" />
<jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time" value="${timestamp}" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Build info</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Build time: </td>
    <td><fmt:formatDate value="${dateValue}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Build number: </td>
    <td>${buildNumber}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Branch: </td>
    <td>${scmBranch}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Maven pom

```
<!-- plugin that sets build number as a maven property -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>create</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <format>{0,date,yyDHHmm}</format>
        <items>
          <item>timestamp</item>
        </items>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <format>{0,date,yyDHHmm}</format>
    <items>
      <item>timestamp</item>
    </items>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<!-- war plugin conf to enable filtering for our file -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>build.jsp</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>.</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

More details about the usage of buildnumber-maven-plugin can be found on the [usage page](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: How does Maven fill in `${buildNumber}` and `${scmBranch}`? In my case, I want to pull from a shell command to get the tag and commit ID from git (I know how to do the shell part).

Comment: @DavidHarkness `buildnumber-maven-plugin` creates those as properties (like explained in its [usage page](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html)). Using a shell script would require a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**: Resources filtering does not work this way for .jsp files. As Pascal Thivent pointed out (thank you) an index.jsp is not a resource but belongs to the webapp.

---

I do not know the exact answer to your question but you could hard-code the buildnumber into the index.jsp file with maven directly when the index.jsp file is copied to the target directory. You only would need to insert a variable into the index.jsp and configure the maven-resource-plugin to enable filtering.

***Example:***

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Title (build: ${buildNumber} )
</head>
```

**Maven Configuration (extract from pom.xml)**

```
<build>

    <!-- Enable Resource Filtering -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <!-- Fetch the SVN build-number into var ${buildNumber} -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

For more information on filtering have a look at the [Maven Filtering Manual](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Comment: It's possible to filter *web resources* but not like this, a JSP is not a *resource*.