# Different resource files root for different environments in struts 2 & sitemesh

Tags: java, css, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I am quite new to Struts 2 and Sitemesh. I am a frontend developer and need to change a lot CSS and JS files. What I want is a method in which I don't have to redeploy the entire project for every char I change in JS and CSS files.

What I thought would be useful is to create a vhost in apache whith the root forwarding to struts resources folders (Tomcat is working on 8080 and apache on 80). In decorator file I defined a variable which I will change when I need to deploy. In work mode will be something like:

```
<s:set var="resourceRoot">http://resource-folder.localhost</s:set>
```

For a CSS link I thought will be nice to have something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<s:url value='${resourceRoot}/resources/css/styles.css' />" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But, when I try to deploy tomcat will deliver the following message:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/decorators/default.jsp
>   (line: 20, column: 20) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag
>   file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

What would be a best practice for what I intend here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy workaround is to host the css files on a simple outsourced webserver, e.g. with python:

```
$ cd /your/dir/to/your/sources
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

... and point your java to this server (e.g.: localhost/styles.css etc)

Edit: Sorry I now read your problem is the attribute tag and you are already trying the way I posted....

Why would you need the variable, can't you set the URL in your java code? You would then be able to use a runtime argument to decide if you need to get the sources from your external server.

Comment: Yes, this is what I intend for developing machine, but it will be deployed on live system and I don't want to change all URLs to fit the new location of resources. I want an easy way to change it throught a variable in java project.

Comment: In your java code you build your url based on the agrument you start your vm. e.g. "-ddevelopment=true". Then in your Java code query the property via "Boolean isDevelopment = System.getProperty("development");" and build your sources url depending on this?

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Don't know yet how to set all this in java.

Comment: Another possibility is if you are using maven. You could use maven filtering to fill properties files which hold your resources url. you will then use maven profiles to decide which url you want to be using. I found  a quick explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195871/how-to-display-buildnumber-in-spring-based-web-application